# What to import to use RolesAllowed with jersey

Tags: java, http, rest, authorization, jersey

I am using jersey to build a restful webservice.
For authorization purpose i implemented a class AuthorizationFilter, that implements ContainerRequestFilter. I am applying this filter in my web.xml as follows:

```
    <init-param>
         <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
         <param-value>filters.AuthorizationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

My AuthorizationFilter sets the SecurityContext of each request, according to the result of the authentication.

```
request.setSecurityContext(new Authorizer(webuser));
```

My Authorizer looks like this:

```
public class Authorizer implements SecurityContext {

    private WebUser webuser;
    private Principal principal;

    public Authorizer(final WebUser webuser) {
        this.webuser = webuser;
        this.principal = new Principal() {

            @Override
            public String getName() {
                return webuser.getUsername();
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getAuthenticationScheme() {
        return SecurityContext.FORM_AUTH;
    }

    @Override
    public Principal getUserPrincipal() {
        return principal;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSecure() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
        return role.equals(webuser.getRole());
    }

}
```

Now i want to annotate the allowed roles for the methods of my endpoints:

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("{id}")
    @RolesAllowed({"EMPLOYEE"})
    @Override
    public Response Retreive(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        return super.Retreive(id);
    }
```

But it says "RolesAllowed cannot be resolved to a type". So my question is a. how to fix this and b. am i doing it right?

Thanks in advance
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of your question: You may be missing a dependency to the Java EE API, where the `RolesAllowed` annotation is defined (see [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/security/RolesAllowed.html))

If you are using Maven to build your project, try adding a dependency to `javax:javaee-web-api:6.0` to your pom.xml.

Comment: I ll try this on my way home :P ty

Comment: This does not work, i guess its because a standard tomcat does not provide the implementation of the api?

Comment: INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\AuspeX\git\zeiterfassung_backend\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\restserver\WEB-INF\lib\javaee-web-api-6.0.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Nov 09, 2012 1:40:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener

Is the result of adding the dependency

Comment: Try using TomEE to run Java EE apps on Tomcat.